# Joining tables with duplicates from 1st table Code Igniter Active Records

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

Working on my project on PHP code igniter,I am implementing an online shopping cart ,I want to join two tables of PRODUCT and PRODUCT_IMAGE.
Product contains Product attributes except 'image' and PRODUCT_IMAGE contains images against each 'product_id'
I have multiples images stored in PRODUCT_IMAGE for each 'product_id' which is a FOREIGN KEY in the table PRODUCT_IMAGE

I want to write such a query using ACTIVE RECORDS such that it gives **only one** of the image from PRODUCT_IMAGE for each product in PRODUCT.

So far I have tried this:

```
//$cat_num is category_number of the products against which we want to get Products  
 $this->db->select('distinct(product_image.product_id),product_image.image,product.name');
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('product.category',$cat_num);
$this->db->join('product_image', 'product.id = product_image.product_id','left');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using "group by" statement has resolved the matter for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->db->select('product_image.product_id, product_image.image, product.name')
         ->from('product')
         ->join('product_image', 'product.id = product_image.product_id')
         ->where("product.category", $cat_num);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result());
}
```

Comment: I think you are not getting the problem.Problem is that I have to get only one of row for image for each product.Actually,there are many product images and we want to display only one